# Length of sum of high-dimensional 3 vectors in terms of their lengths and inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

I have 3 vectors in a high-dimensional euclidean space.  I would like to express the length of their sum in terms of their lengths and inner products. For two vectors, I can do it with the law of cosines:

$c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab\cos\theta$

which in my context translates to:

$||c||^2 =||a||^2+||b||^2 -2 a \cdot b$

(where c = a+b and all are vectors, I project them into the span of a,b to get the triangle and then apply the law of cosines from trig)

How do I do this for 3 vectors, d=a+b+c?

I'll keep working on this and answer my own question if I come up with a solution.

Comment: You can iterate the process, by first obtaining the length of $a+b$ in terms of $||a||$, $||b||$, and $a\cdot b$; then obtain the length of $(a+b)+c$ in terms of $||a+b||$ (which is given in terms of $||a||$, $||b||$ and $a\cdot b$), $||c||$, and $(a+b)\cdot c = a\cdot c + b\cdot c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use associativity:  $$\overline{a}+\overline{b}+\overline{c}=(\overline{a}+\overline{b})+\overline{c}$$
This yields the answer since you already know how to add two vectors.  As a check, notice that the answer has to be the same if I permute $a,b,c$ since addition is commutative.

**Edit:**

Say you have vectors $a,b,c$.  Then $$\|a+b+c\|=\|(a+b)\|^2+\|c\|^2-2(a+b)\cdot c$$
$$=\|(a+b)\|^2+\|c\|^2 -2a\cdot c-2b\cdot c$$
$$=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2+\|c\|^2 -2\left( a\cdot c+b\cdot c+a\cdot b\right)$$

Comment: For anyone reading this, should I have added in the edit or just left it as a hint?  I have trouble deciding these things.

Comment: This was not a homework problem, I am deriving an algorithm, so I appreciate your working things out.  The hint would have taken me another half-hour to figure out how to apply.  Arturo's comment would have been sufficient detail that I would have accepted it as an answer also.

Comment: @Eponymous: Thanks for the feedback!